# Horizontal RecyclerViews inside vertical RecyclerView scrolling jerks

Tags: scroll, android-recyclerview

I am using a layout in which I used multiple RecyclerViews (Horizontal) as a item view of RecyclerView. The problem is that the vertical scrolling is not as smooth as I am expecting.There are some  jerks in while scrolling vertically(Parent RecyclerView).

How to remove these  vertical  scrolling jerks ? I used to set adapters to horizontal RecyclerViews in OnBindViewHolder() method of Parent RecyclerView.

Comment: @JqueryNinja Question is not about how to do that. That is how I did it initially. Actually everybody coming here in this post was doing this same as in the post you shared.We all want solution to the scrolling jerks in this implementation. Check accepted answer, which have improvement over these scrolling jerks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have solved  the  problem.

Scrolling performance is much  better in this case.

Do not set adapters to horizontal `RecyclerViews` in `OnBindViewHolder()` method of Parent `RecyclerView`.

Instead of it set  it  at very first  time  when the  view is created via `onCreateViewHolder()` of  RecyclerView with empty or null dataList.

Just replace the new secondary data list with previous null list at `onBindViewHolder()` and call `notifydataSetChanged()` to `HorizontalAdapetr`.

This is much better than `setAdapter()` in `onBindViewHolder()`.

Comment: I tried doing that but now only the last Parent RecyclerView has any horizontal RecyclerViews. How to solve this?

Comment: Didn't get your question? Could you please provide more details?

Answer (score 3):

## You can try this way

**main activity**

```
public void initialize(List<List<ResponseObject>> responseObjectList) {
    RecyclerView upperRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) this.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    upperRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    VerticalAdapter adapter = new VerticalAdapter(this, responseObjectLists);
    upperRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Vertical recycled view adapter**

```
public class VerticalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VerticalAdapter.Holder> {

    final private SearchActivity activity;
    List<List<ResponseObject>> list;

    public VerticalAdapter(SearchActivity activity, List<List<ResponseObject>> lists) {
        this.list = lists;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.vertical_layout, null);
        return new Holder(itemLayoutView);
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(Holder viewHolder, int position) {
        List<ResponseObject> objectList = list.get(position);
        viewHolder.packageTitle.setText(objectList.get(0).getTag());
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(activity, objectList);
        viewHolder.horizontalRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        viewHolder.horizontalRecyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        viewHolder.horizontalRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public final static class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView packageTitle;
        protected RecyclerView horizontalRecyclerView;

        public Holder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.packageTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycleViewTitle);
            this.horizontalRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            this.horizontalRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.horizontalRecyclerView.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
            this.horizontalRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
            horizontalRecyclerView.setAdapter(null);
        }
    }

    public int getItemCount() {
        return ListUtil.isEmpty(list) ? 0 : list.size();
    }
}
```

**Horizontal recycleview adapter**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends     RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ResponseObject> mainPageResponseList;
    private SearchActivity activity;

    public ImageAdapter(SearchActivity activity, List mainPageResponseList) {
        this.mainPageResponseList = mainPageResponseList;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public ImageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.horizontal_layout_view, null);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        ResponseObject object = mainPageResponseList.get(position);
        Util.setImageUsingGlide(object.getImage(), viewHolder.imageView);
        viewHolder.packageName.setText(object.getDestination());
        viewHolder.packagePrice.setText(object.getPrice() + "");
        viewHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener(null);
    }

    public final static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected ImageView imageView;
        protected TextView packageName;
        protected TextView packagePrice;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.packageImage);
            this.packageName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.packageName);
            this.packagePrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.packagePrice);
        }
    }

    public int getItemCount() {
        return ListUtil.isEmpty(mainPageResponseList) ? 0 : mainPageResponseList.size();
    }
}
```

**main_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"> 

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivHolidayMainImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivHotelImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/ivHolidayMainImage"
           android:background="@drawable/gradient_from_up_hotel_image" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="250dp">
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/mainPackageTitle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Popular Pick"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="12dp" />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/mainPackageName"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/mainPackageTitle"
                            android:text="Andaman Islands"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="18dp" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/mainPackagePrice"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="25000"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="18dp" />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/journeyType"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/mainPackagePrice"
                            android:text="Popular Pick"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="12dp" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
         android:background="@drawable/gradient_from_down_hotel_image" />
        </app.viaindia.views.ViaLinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_sms_black"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

**vertical_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/recycleViewTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:text="Beaches"
    android:textColor="@color/black_light"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

**holizontal_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:viaCustom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/packageImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/cheese_1" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNightAndDays"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="3 Night/4 days"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to notifydatasetChanged() in onbindViewHolder() not setAdapter(). SetAdapter() is more time consuming than notifying datset change.

Comment: lot of improvement using above method