# How to use horizontal view pager inside recycler view

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I want to use viewpager inside recycler view and set data on pager from api.

For more details, i'm adding my code in question.

**My Code is**

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final worksheetAdapter.CustomViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final int a = position;            rec_worksheet.setTag(position);
```

*Set text on TextView*

```
        holder.question.setText(userlist.get(position).get("ques"));
        holder.question.startAnimation(animFadein);
        holder.tvans1.setText(userlist.get(position).get("ans1"));
        holder.tvans1.startAnimation(animFadein);
        holder.tvans2.setText(userlist.get(position).get("ans2"));
        holder.tvans2.startAnimation(animFadein);
        holder.tvans3.setText(userlist.get(position).get("ans3"));
        holder.tvans3.startAnimation(animFadein);
        holder.tvans4.setText(userlist.get(position).get("ans4"));
        holder.tvans4.startAnimation(animFadein);
        holder.submitbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if(position == userlist.size()  - 1){
            holder.submitbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        holder.queNo.setText("Question No "+String.valueOf(position+1));
        holder.tvTotalQue.setText("Total Ques. "+String.valueOf(userlist.size()));
        holder.tvSubName.setText(userlist.get(position).get("subject_name"));

        holder.submitbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                submit();
            }
        });
```

*Check if first answer is equals to correct answer*

```
        holder.llAns1.setTag(position);
        holder.llAns1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 v.getTag(position);
                   holder.llAns1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.que_correct_back); 
                   holder.llAns2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green);
                   holder.llAns3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green);
                   holder.llAns4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green);

                allAns.add(userlist.get(position).get("ans1"));

                correctans = userlist.get(position).get("correctans");

                if(holder.tvans1.getText().toString().equals(correctans)){
                    CorrectAns.add(userlist.get(position).get("ans1"));     
                }else {
                    try {
                        wrongAns.add(userlist.get(position).get("ans1"));
                        CorrectAns.remove(position);
                    }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){}
                }
            }
        });
```

*Check if secound answer is equals to correct answer*

```
        holder.llAns2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.llAns2.setTag(position);

                holder.llAns2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.que_correct_back); 
                holder.llAns1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green);
                holder.llAns3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green);
                holder.llAns4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green);

                correctans = userlist.get(position).get("correctans");
                if(holder.tvans2.getText().equals(correctans)){
                    CorrectAns.add(userlist.get(position).get("ans2"));                    
                }else {
                    try {
                        wrongAns.add(userlist.get(position).get("ans2"));
                        CorrectAns.remove(correctans);
                    }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){}

                }
            }
        });
```

*Check if third answer is equals to correct answer*

```
        holder.llAns3.setTag(position);
        holder.llAns3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                holder.llAns3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.que_correct_back); 
                holder.llAns2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green);
                holder.llAns1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green);
                holder.llAns4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green);
                correctans = userlist.get(position).get("correctans");

                if(holder.tvans3.getText().equals(correctans)){
                    CorrectAns.add(userlist.get(position).get("ans3"));


                }else {
                    try {
                        wrongAns.add(userlist.get(position).get("ans3"));
                        CorrectAns.remove(correctans);
                    }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){}

                }

            }
        });
```

*Check if forth answer is equals to correct answer*

```
        holder.llAns4.setTag(position);
        holder.llAns4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                holder.llAns4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.que_correct_back);
                holder.llAns3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green);
                holder.llAns2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green);
                holder.llAns1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green);
                correctans = userlist.get(position).get("correctans");


                if(holder.tvans4.getText().equals(correctans)){
                    CorrectAns.add(userlist.get(position).get("ans4"));
                    Log.d("corrAns1",String.valueOf(CorrectAns));

                }else {
                    try {
                        wrongAns.add(userlist.get(position).get("ans1"));
                        CorrectAns.remove(correctans);
                    }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){}
                    Log.d("corrAns2",String.valueOf(CorrectAns));
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a viewpager inside a recyclerview. If you want to use horizontal swiping inside a recyclerview then you will have to use a recyclerview inside a recyclerview. This child recyclerview will be have a horizontal layout.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243362/horizontal-recyclerviews-inside-vertical-recyclerview-scrolling-jerks) precisely addresses that.

For the 2nd issue:

Add the following lines

```
holder.llAns2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green); 
holder.llAns1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green);
holder.llAns3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green);
holder.llAns4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green);
```

below this line:

```
if(position == userlist.size()  - 1){
    holder.submitbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

for 3rd issue:
    //add this below your adapter class
    private ArrayList selectedOptions;

in your onbindviewholder add this below `holder.llAns4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green)`

```
if(selectedOptions.get(position) != null){
    switch (selectedOptions.get(position)){
       case 1:
        holder.llAns1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.que_correct_back);
        break;
       case 2:
        holder.llAns2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.que_correct_back);
        break;
       case 3:
        holder.llAns3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.que_correct_back);
        break;
       case 4:
        holder.llAns4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.que_correct_back);
        break;
     }
    }
```

I have answered 3 things now. Please ask new stackoverflow question for further issues.

Comment: I have list of questions and set it on horizontal recycler View ... user select any ans from all three options but after four index one ans automatically marked.

Comment: so? what to do next?

Comment: that is happening because recyclerview is reusing the previous view. You will have to setChecked() of radio button to false in your onbindviewholder before you put the rest of the code.

Comment: which radio button ?

Comment: what view are you using for options?

Comment: In recyclerView ,there are four textViews and set different option on them .. onClick of any textView  change its background color but after few index automatically changed textView color

Comment: Can you edit your question and copy paste the onbindviewholder of the recyclerview? I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: it show an error that "it look like your post is mostly code please add some more detail" what to do?

Comment: that means you should add more details...just copy oaste the onbindviewholder parts...not the who code

Comment: Now problem is that , when i scroll back then selected views cleared automatically..

Comment: You will need to store the options selected. And you will need to pass it in the onbindviewholder

Comment: ya but actually i don't know how to do, i already done many efforts but no result found

Comment: but if i store all marked answer into an array and compare them like

Comment: if(ansAr.get(i).equals("ans1")){ holder.llAns2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.que_correct_back); 
holder.llAns1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green);
holder.llAns3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green);
holder.llAns4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_strock_green);} then same issue occurred like before

Comment: As I have solved the basic issue, can you mark the answer correct?
I'll solve this issue in chat after you mark the answer

Comment: holder.llAns1, holder.llAns2, holder.llAns3, holder.llAns4 are static they are not dynamic so how i can get their position ?

Comment: because i'm select an option from them

Comment: add the line in their respective onclicklistener `selectedOptions.get(position) = 1 or 2 or 3 or 4;`

Comment: holder.llAns3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    selectedOption.get(position) = 1;

Comment: holder.llAns3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    MyselectedOption.get(position) = 1;}} is not working

Comment: my mistake. Use `MyselectedOption.set(postion, 1);` You can't use two setnclickListener, just add this line to the existing one.

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 at MyselectedOption.set(postion, 1);