# Vertical recyclerview (which includes horizontal recyclerview) is not working properly

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, nested

I have a fragment which includes two recycler views (vertical and horizontal).

I write all the adapters for these 2 recycler views (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243362/horizontal-recyclerviews-inside-vertical-recyclerview-scrolling-jerks#33434457)) but the problem is that the outer (vertical) recyclerview just shows the first item and it doesn't show rest of the items. My attempted code is as follows:

**aFragment.java**

```
...
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new  LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()) {
    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        return false;
    }
};
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
adapter = new AppletCategoryAdapter(applets, getActivity());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
...
```

**AppletCategoryAdapter.java:**

```
public class AppletCategoryAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AppletCategoryAdapter.SimpleViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<AppletItemsCategory> mData;
    ...

    public class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final TextView title;
        public RecyclerView horizontalList;

        public SimpleViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.applet_category_item_name);
            this.horizontalList = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.applet_items_horizontal_list);
            this.horizontalList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(horizontalList.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
            this.horizontalList.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
            horizontalList.setAdapter(null);
        }
    }


    public AppletCategoryAdapter(List<AppletItemsCategory> data, Context context) {
        mData = data;
        mContext = context;
    }

     public SimpleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.applet_category_item, parent, false);
        return new SimpleViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SimpleViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        List<Applet> applets = mData.get(position).getProductOffers();
        holder.title.setText(mData.get(position).getCategoryName());
        AppletCardAdapter appletCardAdapter = new AppletCardAdapter(applets,mContext);
        holder.horizontalList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        holder.horizontalList.setAdapter(appletCardAdapter);
        holder.horizontalList.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        appletCardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }
}
```

**AppletCardAdapter.java:**

```
public class AppletCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AppletCardAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context context;

    //List of channels
    List<Applet> applets;

    public AppletCardAdapter(List<Applet> applets, Context ctx) {
        this.applets = applets;
        this.context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.applets_list, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Applet applet =  applets.get(position);
        holder.setIsRecyclable(true);
        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(Config.BASE_URL + applet.getImage(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
        holder.imageView.setImageUrl(Config.BASE_URL + applet.getImage(), imageLoader);
        holder.textViewName.setText(applet.getName());
        holder.textViewDescription.setText(applet.getDescription());
        try {
            holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(applet.getColor()));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("iotel", "Unknown color");
        }
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openAppletDetailFragment(applet);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return applets.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public NetworkImageView imageView;
        public TextView textViewName;
        public TextView textViewDescription;
        public CardView cardView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.appletImage);
            textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.appletName);
            textViewDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.appletDescription);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.appletCard);
        }
    }
}
```

**a_fragment.xml:** (containing vertical recyclerView)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleInverse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**applet_category_item.xml** (containing horizontal recyclerView):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/applet_category_item_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/applet_items_horizontal_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**applet_list.xml** (shows the content of each item in horizontal recyclerView):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        style="@style/MyCardViewStyle"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardDefaultBg"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/appletCard">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/appletImage" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ir.iotel.MyTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:textSize="9pt"
                    android:textColor="@color/fontSecondary"
                    android:id="@+id/appletName" />
                <ir.iotel.MyTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:textColor="@color/fontSecondary"
                    android:id="@+id/appletDescription" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout >
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at this code : https://github.com/hardworker93/carousels/tree/master

you should try this :

**In Fragment**

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);      
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

**In Adapter :**

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        List<Item> RowItems = mRows.get(position);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);     
        holder.mRecyclerViewRow.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        holder.mRecyclerViewRow.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RowRecyclerAdapter rowsRecyclerAdapter = new RowRecyclerAdapter(mContext,RowItems);         
        holder.mRecyclerViewRow.setAdapter(rowsRecyclerAdapter);
```

In layout applet_category_item :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">
```

Comment: Using `RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new  LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)...`, yes, I try it but it doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, it keeps not working yet, thanks anyway

Comment: Try to set colored background on you different widget to see if the problem come from row or recycler ?

Comment: It seems that the rows are rendered, but they are in infinite distance from each other. Meaning that when I scroll down the screen infinitely, the second/third/... rows are appeared while when I scroll up a little, they got disappeared.

Comment: Remove the setNestedScrollingEnable to try, and also, in the layout of the row, change layout_heigt to150dp

Comment: Could you please give me a link which explains this process? I might make a mistake in my code snippets. I want to develop a fragment such as Google Play Store's first page (fragment). @Dany Poplawec

Comment: @inverted_index that happens when your layout (for the item you want to show in your recyclerView) has width set to "match_parent". Make sure the width and height of the root layout is set to "wrap_content" or a specific size. (The specific size you can vary by screen size, if you want.)

Comment: to make my recyclerView horizontal, you only need two things: 1) `new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);` and 2) in the xml for the RecyclerView, add `android:scrollbars="horizontal"`

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of hours, I finally overcome the problem. The logic behind the Adapter, Fragment, and RecyclerViews is correct and fully functional.Even, it can be used as a template for implementing nested recycler views (horizontal recycler view inside a vertical one). However, a tiny mistake on design of the horizontal recycler view *(applet_category_item.xml)* leads to almost an enormous bug on the application.

Long story short, It seems that `RelativeLayout` shouldn't be used in this situation. As I remove it, all the things go well and life becomes sweeter :)

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/applet_category_item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/applet_items_horizontal_list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```