# A horizontal recycler inside a vertical recycler. What is the best practice for this situation?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontal recycler(s) inside a vertical recycler. I'm currently implementing a multiple `viewholder` adapter, but I need a bit clarification if the way I'm doing it is a bad practice.

A picture of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Where should I create the horizontal recycler? In this SO answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44603986/11110509

They create a `new HorizontalRecycler` in the `onBindViewHolder` method. I am unsure if this is good or not. What is the best practice to implement `multiple horizontal recyclers` in this situation?

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(holder.getItemViewType() == HORIZONTAL_RECYCLER_ITEM) {

            HorizontalFragmentViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = (HorizontalFragmentViewHolder) holder;
            //Should I create a new horizontal recycler here everytime? Doesn't seem like a good idea
        }else{

            SavedPostViewHolder postViewHolder = (SavedPostViewHolder) holder;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't creating a new recycler view object each time onBindViewHolder is being invoked, that happens very constrained as to how many horizontal recycler-views can be accommodated on the UI. You will, however, have to create an adapter and assign to the recyclerView object in your HorizontalFragmentViewHolder. IMHO, the approach itself is the clean way out.

```
holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(new HorizontalRecyclerViewAdapter(context,horizontal.list))
holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
holder.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Comment: How does it not create a new recyclerview object when it has the new syntax? I am extremely confused there.

Comment: You are probably having a layout file, which contains a child recyclerView object. That layout file is inflated and a new RecyclerView object is created only a few times, based on screen dimensions, based on how many views can the entire screen contain. It happens when onCreateView is called, which happens only a limited number of times. In the onBindViewHolder method, you're creating a Adapter only, which is really cheap in memory than a View. The reuse principle is explained in the following mindorks document. [link] (https://blog.mindorks.com/how-does-recyclerview-work-internally)